# wp_redirect not working when going to www version of site

Tags: wp-redirect

The following function works perfectly when logged-in visitors go to http://sitename.com, taking them to the site homepage. When logged-in visitors go to http://www.sitename.com, however, they're incorrectly redirected to http://sitename.com/splashpage. Does anyone know what's causing this?

I have tried switching my site settings to use http://www.sitename.com as the WordPress and Site Address URLs, but that simply reverses the issue so it incorrectly redirects when a logged-in user goes to http://sitename.com.

```
// REDIRECT USERS TO SPLASH PAGE IF THEY'RE NOT LOGGED IN
add_action ('template_redirect','mkm_restrict_access',1);
function mkm_restrict_access() {
    $url = site_url('/splashpage/');
    if (is_page('splashpage') || is_page('login')) {
        //do nothing
    } elseif (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        wp_redirect( $url ); 
        exit; 
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is there perhaps a better action to use to call this redirect? Something that fires after the page redirects from http://www.example.com to http://example.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, though this is the lamest solution ever: I hooked into wp_footer instead of template_redirect. If anyone has a better solution or place to hook in I'd love to hear about it - thanks!

EDIT:
That wasn't the fix I thought it was. Turned out I was writing the function poorly, and did need to be using template_redirect. See [Cannot get redirect working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26163/cannot-get-redirect-working)