# Cannot get redirect working

Tags: wp-redirect

I can't get wp_redirect working correctly? I thought I'd figured this out (see [wp_redirect not working when going to www version of site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24846/wp-redirect-not-working-when-going-to-www-version-of-site)) but apparently not; no idea what changed between last week when it was working and now. I tried simplifying the function down but using the following I get an infinite-redirect error:

```
add_action ('after_setup_theme','mkm_restrict_access',10);
function mkm_restrict_access() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_page('splashpage') && !is_page('login')) {
        wp_redirect('http://localhost.localdomain/clientname/wp/splashpage/'); 
        exit; 
    }
}
```

I've tried using wp_footer and almost everything up the chain in terms of calling the function but nothing seems to help. I am running [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) and [User Domain Whitelist](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-domain-whitelist/), if that matters. I tried disabling them but it didn't help.

I suspect I'm doing something REALLY STUPID. :( Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

none of those conditionals will work at after_theme_setup. Look at the [Action Reference page in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) for the order actions are executed in a request. Try hooking `template_redirect` instead.